# Soundcloud embed Timeout & wget returning Error 500

Tags: embed, soundcloud, firewall

I have a wordpress blog in a VPS (Centos 6.8 x86) which some pages have a soundcloud embed. Whenever I try to view one of this pages, I receive a timeout error (http://prntscr.com/bpmm90).

```
GET
http://soundcloud.com/oembed
?maxwidth=0
&maxheight=0
&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F10de10%2Fsemana-dos-10-20-270616
&format=json

Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Ok, I thought maybe I was doing something wrong in Wordpress, so I tried to 'wget' the same URL and... ERROR 500.

```
wget 'http://soundcloud.com'
--2016-07-06 18:46:01--  http://soundcloud.com/
Resolving soundcloud.com... 72.21.91.127
Connecting to soundcloud.com|72.21.91.127|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2016-07-06 18:46:31 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

However, it all works fine if I try the same things on another server. I've already thought about if I was somehow blocked from accesing soundcloud through my VPS, but I barely did any call to the service.

The url in question is: http://soundcloud.com/oembed?maxwidth=0&maxheight=0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2F10de10%2Fsemana-dos-10-20-270616&format=json

Comment: Did you finally figure this out? I'm currently having the exact same problem.

Comment: @Anastis The first thing that worked for me was changing my VPS location from NYC1 to NYC3 (digitalocean, in my case). I know, not the best 'explanation for a solution' here. However, rarely I still get the timeout error but it lasts just for a few moments.